# Does The thin PVC Flexible skirting goes well on parquet?

Tags: flooring, skirting, parquet

I am currently placing a parquet (Oiled Engineered Wood Flooring) in my home which contains several walls which are rounded, (the sharper round has around radius of 1m)

For the skirting I would need something Flexible.

For the moment I am contemplating a simple PVC Flexible skirting we can buy in rolls, ([example](https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/gygAAOSwmLlX85t8/s-l1600.jpg))
Main reason for this is not about price, but rather that the skirting would then be quite thin: easier placing of cupboards, less dust collection.

I could not find a good review about such Flexible skirting on parquet and experience about it.
Does it goes well with parquet?

Edit:

Will it fill the expansion gap properly? what is the life expectancy of such skirting? any care required? It has to be glued on the floor too, will it be fine also with parquet expansion?  On a curved wall, will the bottom stick properly, and also on the long term?
Any experience to share on this?

Comment: I think it would help people understand better what you're doing if you would include some pictures of your actual situation, as well as a link to the skirting you're referring to. The "goes well" portion of your question addresses "decorating", which is off-topic and should be removed from the question. The "glued to the floor" part seems odd and needs that link so someone can review the installation instructions. "How does it do with rounded walls?" is a bit vague - How does it look? Does it handle installation on curved surfaces? Not sure what you're after.

Comment: @FreeMan Thank you for the review, I have updated with an example of Flexible skirting, in this example as in many, there are no parquet expansion gap, so basically it does not say much about the real thing. Also I could not find a real life experience and review of this. It is not really decoration (except if skirting is decorating), I am more interested in: will it fill the gap properly? life expectancy? care required? On a curved wall, will the bottom stick properly, also on the long term? let me know if the question is too global or not well formulated.

Comment: "It has to be glued on the floor too,"  I don't think you **ever** glue skirting to the floor.  Floors and walls move relative to each other.

Comment: @SteveWellens I am bit surprised too, but in the example, or if I google search 'PVC Flexible Skirting' a lot of them come with double tape wall and floor... which brought me to think that it may still be something? Let me know if it is something that indeed should then not be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**How long will it look good?**

Zero days.   It is hideous.   You bought wood floor and want to ruin it with this?

**Why are vinyl baseboards installed?**

For "mop" situations.   You would install these for example in a hospital room that is to be mopped.   There is also a variety you install on walls when installing commercial carpet.   They are generally cheap, easy to install/replace, handle big issues well (furniture bumps, kicks, whatever) but get worn down quickly with foot traffic.

**Will it fill the expansion gap?**

Sure if you bend it in half and install half on the wall and half on the floor.   Let me say I have never seen baseboards installed like this in my life.   They would be a lint/dirt trap.   They would get stepped on, furniture would be on top of it... all kinds of issues.

**What should you use?**

If you do not want to go through the process of warping normal wood trim to fit the curves in your wall then get trim designed to do this [like this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Flex-Trim-HD-618-9-16-in-x-5-1-4-in-x-144-in-Polyurethane-Flexible-Base-Moulding-90098/202961474).   Please just take the vinyl/rubber solutions off the table unless you are living in commercial office space.

Comment: That is a very good answer, but it seems that I cannot open the link provided from my country (germany). would you mind providing an other link? From the link name, I am searching Polyurethane baseboards and seems indeed a great baseboard to use indeed.

Comment: Trying searching - "Polyurethane Flexible Base Moulding" or "Flex Trim".